# What ends up in a Hadoop Reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When items are mapped to reducers based on keys, does a single reducer receive a List that contains a single key, or does the reducer contain all the keys that hashed to that reducer?

Example:
I have 7 unique ids that I am mapping on.

When I write my reduce method can I assume that when I loop through all the elements in the list I will only have 1 unique id? Or could I have more then one id in a reducer?

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `reduce()` will have a single key and one or more values. This is evident from the signature of the Map.reduce() method: `reduce(KEYIN key, Iterable<VALUEIN> values, Context context)`

Some examples:

- If your mapper calls `Context.write()` 10 times with the same key and 10 different values, the reduce() method will be called once, and the `values` iterator will provide the 10 different values.
- If your mapper calls `Context.write()` 10 times with 10 different keys, `reduce()` will be called 10 times, each time with a different key.

Keep in mind that this is a simplification of the default case. You can use custom grouping comparators and other techniques to change this behavior.

Also, remember that, depending on your cluster's setup, the various reducers may not be running on the same machine as one another, nor on the same machine as the mappers.